# Unable to get response with WebRequest of method post

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I want to authenticate the users who visit my website using google's OAUTH2.0.

I have successfully got the authorization_code in response and now I am facing problem when I make a 'POST request' to Google when getting an access token. The problem is that the request is being continued over the time and I'm not getting any response.

Is there anything wrong in the code I have written below?

```
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
postData.Append("code=" + Request.QueryString["code"]);
postData.Append("&client_id=123029216828.apps.googleusercontent.com");
postData.Append("&client_secret=zd5dYB9MXO4C5vgBOYRC89K4");
postData.Append("&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4180/GAuth.aspx&grant_type=authorization_code");

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code=" + Request.QueryString["code"] + "&client_id=124545459218.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={zfsgdYB9MXO4C5vgBOYRC89K4}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4180/GAuth.aspx&grant_type=authorization_code");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string addons = "/o/oauth2/token?code=" + Request.QueryString["code"] + "&client_id=123029216828.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={zd5dYB9MXO4C5vgBOYRC89K4}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4180/GAuth.aspx&grant_type=authorization_code";

request.ContentLength = addons.Length;

Stream str = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(str);
string a = r.ReadToEnd();

str.Close();
r.Close();
```

Comment: You're building up your `postData` string and not doing anything with it. Can you explain what `addons` and `postData` are for? Are you trying to POST one or both of these strings?

Comment: addons for content length calculation. As you said i am not using post data since i mentioned everything in webrequest.create itself

Comment: its working... Thanks 'JoshVarty' for ur answer.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I thought it was irrelevant to your problem, but I've un-deleted it now that you said it helped. Glad to hear everything worked out.

Comment: You have stated exact solution to my problem. Everything worked fine with the code you have modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you just have a few minor mistakes in your code. As it stands, you're not actually POST-ing anything. I'm assuming you intend to send the `postData` string.

The following should work:

```
//Build up your post string
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
postData.Append("code=" + Request.QueryString["code"]);
postData.Append("&client_id=123029216828.apps.googleusercontent.com");
postData.Append("&client_secret=zd5dYB9MXO4C5vgBOYRC89K4");
postData.Append("&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4180/GAuth.aspx&grant_type=authorization_code");

//Create a POST WebRequest
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code=" + Request.QueryString["code"] + "&client_id=124545459218.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={zfsgdYB9MXO4C5vgBOYRC89K4}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4180/GAuth.aspx&grant_type=authorization_code");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

//Write your post string to the body of the POST WebRequest
var sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
sw.Write(postData.ToString());
sw.Close();

//Get the response and read it
var response = request.GetResponse();
var raw_result_as_string = (new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
```

You were just missing the part where you attached the string to your POST WebRequest.